# Apache proxying for / but not for subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2

Here is the relevant part of my config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  <Location "/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I visit `http://mydomain.com/` it appears to proxy as it should, however if I visit `http://mydomain.com/subdir` I get a

> This page appears to be broken

This isn't what I want as I want all requests to http://mydomain.com/ and its subdirectories to be proxied. There is no corresponding error in the error.log.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try delete(not necessary):

```
<Location "/">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

and add:

```
<proxy>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</proxy>
ProxyRequests Off
```